# ggplot2 GLMM poisson model for rates

Tags: r, ggplot2, poisson-distribution

I gave a question about plotting the results of a GLMM Poisson model with an offset term and two random effects:

```
model <- glmer(dv~x1+x2+x3+x4 + offset(log(time))+(1|group1)+(1|group2), data=mydata,family=poisson)
```

I first plotted the predicted scores:

```
mydata$predicted <- predict(model, type="response")
```

Then I plotted the predictions on the rate scale:

```
ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=x1, y=predicted, group=interaction(group1, group2))) + geom_line() + 
   xlab("x1") + 
   ylab("Predicted Rate of events")
```

I believe these two models are equivalent:

```
ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=x1, y=dv/time, group=interaction(group1, group2))) +
   geom_line() + 
   xlab("x1") + 
   ylab("Predicted Rate of events")
```

I was wondering if these models are Ok. Also, since I have two random groups, I
added that interaction term to be able to represent them both, I am not sure that is correct.